# Redirecting to a new tab in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have seen this question being asked many times here, but I couldn't get an answer that works!

i am trying to redirect to a load.php TO A NEW TAB using the following script:

```
echo '<script>window.open("load.php","_blank)</script>';
```

for some reason it is not working and it stays on the same page.

> i am using chrome!

is there any possible way to redirect to a new tab?
thanks a lot

Comment: most browsers stop this by defult

Comment: like @rtfm said, this auto-opening is prevented by the browsers, because you could render the same script in the load.php, which would result in an infinite loop of opening new tabs.. The browser will only allow it programmatically on some user event, like a click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers will block `window.open` unless it is a result of a direct user interaction i.e. the `onclick` event handle of an anchor tag being fired.

There are ways you can try and "trick" popup blockers, but it is unreliable and considered bad practice. If a user has chosen to enable a popup blocker, it should be respected.

What I would suggest is to also add a link on your page along the lines of the following:

```
<a href="load.php" target="_blank">Click here</a> if the window does not open in a seperate window.
```

This would ensure that the user can still open the window manually should it be supressed by a popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a quote mark after _blank.

Try this:

```
echo '<script>window.open("load.php","_blank")</script>';
```

Comment: thanks for fast answer, but still the new tab is blocked by chrome!